# Can I stop supervisor if its program errors too many times?

Tags: php, laravel-4, supervisord

I have supervisor keeping a php command running, however the command is queue:listen that listens for a beanstalkd queue and statrs processing jobs.

However, beanstalkd for whatever reason stops working and so queue:listen just throws an exception and quits as soon as its run, and supervisor keeps starting it. So I have a 1.65GB laravel.log file full of beanstalkd driver exceptions.

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Pheanstalk_Exception_ConnectionException' with message 'Socket error 110: Connection timed out (connecting to localhost:11300)' in /var/www/scouter/vendor/pda/pheanstalk/classes/Pheanstalk/Socket/NativeSocket.php:35
```

How can I resolve this? Is there some way to tell supervisor the difference between the command breaking because of a specific PHP exception and something else?

Or some way to stop re-running the command if it breaks a number of times within 5 minutes or something?

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong issue. Did you script that keeps throwing exceptions

Comment: Did I script? Beanstalkd is not working, the queue:listen is working correctly to throw the exception. But Supervisor does not know that.

Comment: Beanstalkd should not just "stop working". You need to look into your server logs and work out why.

Comment: Maybe try switching queue drivers to Redis and see if you get a similar issue.

Comment: See the error. For whatever reason it did. And I think I know why. But this issue still remains. If it breaks again, it will do so silently and this will happen again.

Comment: The error is that the connection has failed. That is *because* the Beanstalkd service has stopped - not *why* the Beankstalkd service stopped. You should be working out *why* the service is stopping - it should not be doing that - it should be reliable.

Comment: Correct. But again, supervisor has no clue why. All it sees is the command it is to run has stopped running, it will just restart the queue command again and again.

Comment: If only things always ran as they are supposed to..